# Javascript match and replace with unicode

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

I have some javascript which reads some cookies, and does some matching. I am using groupings to catch parts of a regular expression and use them later. I am having an issue with unicode characters though. If I have a character like \u25BA ►, when I find this character in a grouping, it returns the string '\u25BA' instead of the unicode character I am looking for. If I specify the character, I can fix the problem, but I can't get it to work more generally.
The following will work as I want it to:

```
var matches=theOnclick.match(/.*\(event, ?"([^"]*)", ?"([^"]*)".*\)/);
var expand=matches[1].replace(/\\u25BA/, '\u25BA');
```

but this will not work:

```
var expand=matches[1].replace(/\\u([0-9A-Z])/, '\u\1');
```

any suggestions?

More info:
Thanks for your answers. Let me add a little more background. I think the problem is is that I am getting my matches from an "onclick" on a span. I've included a slightly more detailed example below. If I have a normal string with unicode characters in it, when I do a match, I get the unicode characters. However, when I grab the string from the value of the onclick, I get the unicode escape sequences instead. So I have been trying to convert the unicode escape sequences back into the unicode characters. I hope that makes sense. Perhaps there is another way to do it.

In the example below, bar behaves as I want it to, and foo does not.

```
<html>
<body>
<span id='foo' onclick='expandCollapse(event, "►", "▼");'>foo</span>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var foo= document.getElementById('foo').onclick+'';
alert(foo);
var foomatches=foo.match(/.*\(event, ?"([^"]*)", ?"([^"]*)".*\)/);
alert(foomatches);
var bar='expandCollapse(event, "►", "▼");'
var barmatches=bar.match(/.*\(event, ?"([^"]*)", ?"([^"]*)".*\)/);
alert(barmatches);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think your \1 is wrong.  It should be like:

```
"\u2603".replace(/(.)/, "$1"))
```

$1 is a back-reference in the replacement text.

But I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do.  Keep in mind \u can only be used with unicode *literals*.  So the \u in the regex matches a literal \ then a literal u.  And the \u in the replacement text is a u.

Answer (score 1):

what about

```
var expand=matches[1].replace(/\\u([0-9A-Z])/, '\1');
```

?  I don't think you need the escaped `\u` there.